# Filter warning types in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-contracts, visual-studio-extensions

In Visual Studio 2010, all warnings share the same output window:

- Compiler Warnings
- Code Analysis Output
- Code Contracts Output

Is there any way to filter those? For example, I'd like to display only the code analysis warnings separately. Is there any option or extension to do that?